# Maintain Youtube Thumbnail quality on stopVideo

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I'm working on a page for a client where they have some youtube embeds in a slider.  I'm currently stopping the video with `player.stopVideo()` when the user changes slides.  What I've noticed is that the initial video thumbnail gets replaced with a lower quality thumbnail after executing `player.stopVideo()`.  I think this is a bug with the API, but is there a known work around?

I cannot just remove and replace the iframe element because it lives in a slider.  Doing so would cause lots of content jumps for the user and would seriously degrade the UX.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you sold this? I have the same issue. The only workaround i have found it is reloading iframe after the stopping the video.

Comment: I ended up working around it rather than solving it. I created an overlay layer on top of the video that contained the high res image from youtube (there's a url to grab it, i can dig it up if you need).  Then I added two event handler: a click handler to hide the overlay and play the video and a handler to show the overlay when the video is paused.  It works well enough.  Let me know if you need any more details.